# How to avoid updating my password in DB when it is encrypted with bcrypt?

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, spring, bcrypt

I update my data by passing an object to my service (i'm using angularjs and spring)

The data is user details

the thing is I can't update other info without changing/typing the password again

to get a clearer information please check this photo
[image]

I update them separately but when I edit the personal details the password being saved is the encrypted password from the database

My java getter and setters for password are:

```
public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        this.password =  passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    }
```

and the object I pass is:

```
  var profile = {
                "id": $scope.userData.id,
                "firstName": $scope.first,
                "middleName": $scope.mid,
                "lastName": $scope.last,
                "emailAddress": $scope.mail,
                "bday": $scope.bday,
                "contactNo": $scope.num,
                "address":$scope.add,
                "gender":$scope.gender,
                "username": $scope.userData.username,
                "password": $scope.userData.password,
                "role": $scope.userData.role
            }
```

where `$scope.userData` is the current user's data and the other scopes are user input

is there a way to update my table without touching password?

Comment: Seperating the form or putting a button that link to the password change page might be easier and cleaner.

Comment: Can i have some presicions on what you are trying to do? "I can't update other info without changing/typing the password again": is this obligation set by you on purpose or a constraint you have? Is your user logged in at this point? If yes, why would it be mandatory to send the password again to edit his profile?

Comment: @Kaddath If I didn't put the password in the json while updating it, it will save null

Comment: @Stasis it is a separated form

Comment: I mean by removing the right part of your page(the username and 
 password part) altogether and putting it in another page. And i think you have to autofill those page too if not by the way you are saying it you load a new form into the page which they have to fill everything up everytime they want to edit just 1 field?

Comment: I don't need to fill the other form to make it work. using $scope.userData I am reusing old data to update it

Comment: the problem is the encrypted password will be encrypted again

Comment: Are you using a solution that updates the fields in database automatically server-side? Do you have some control over it? We probably need this part of code to help you. You'd want to modify it either to not update db when password is not given, or separate your db profile update in different parts so that you don't need to provide password for your edit profile form.